# Add a custom text to admin footer in a Custom Post Type page

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, hooks

I want to customize the footer text in a Custom Post Type admin page.
I have a plugin that creates this custom post type and want to add in it a function to customize admin_footer_text.

As you can see in code below I can change the footer text, but only globaly.

```
function my_custom_footer_admin_text () {
    echo 'my custom message,';
}
add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'my_custom_footer_admin_text');
```

Does someone knows the hook of a custom post type page? Or how can I change the footer text of a certain Custom Post Type page?

Comment: What is a _Custom Post Type page_? Are you talking about `post.php` for that CPT? Or `post-new.php`? Or both? Or something else?

Comment: Hi, I'm talking about 'wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=my_post_type' and 'wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=my_post_type'; pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do. Put the following in your `functions.php`

```
if (in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('edit.php', 'post.php', 'post-new.php')))
    add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'my_custom_footer_admin_text');

function my_custom_footer_admin_text($text) {
    $post_type = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'post_type');
    if (! $post_type)
        $post_type = get_post_type(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'post'));

    if ('my_post_type' == $post_type)
        return 'my custom message';

    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [number of functions related to working with post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Post_Type), such as [`get_post_type()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_type/) and [`is_singular()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_singular/).

Note that conditional tags are meant to be used primarily inside of running loop and in more complex sites `$post` global might no longer hold instance of post expected and require resetting via [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_reset_postdata/) or something more elaborate, depending on what is going on in page.

Comment: He is talking about _Admin footer_... ;)

Comment: Oops. :) Logic roughly applies to loops in admin, but probably question has terminology mixed up after all...

Answer (score 0):

U can use

```
function my_custom_footer_admin_text () {

if(is_post_type_archive('custom-post-name')||is_singular('custom-post-name') ){

    echo 'my custom message,';
}

}
add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'my_custom_footer_admin_text');
```

Comment: But this will remove default footer in the other pages, and only worked to 'wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=my_post_type'. For the page  'wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=my_post_type' it does not works.